# Using a python list in a Check Box Selection Form in Flask WTF

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to use a python list as the options for a check box selection form.
So you can select the items in the list that you want and submit the form to use those values.

Which form field do I use in my form?

What would my html file look like?

I think the .html page should look like this.

```
    <form>
        {% for item in list %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="modList" value={{item}}>{{item}}<br>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

But I can't figure out what to make the form field in forms.py.

http://packages.python.org/Flask-WTF/

There is no Checkbox form on that page.

I can use

```
    {{form.modList(formdata = list)}}
```

But it just displays an emtpy checkbox with no text

Comment: it would help if you told us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. If you're using checkboxes, I assume you'll want to return the value of each one. If so, then each one should be a distinct property of the WTForm instance you're using.

If you're only wanting to return the values checked, WTForms offers the [`wtforms.fields.SelectMultipleField`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectMultipleField). That would print a dropbox wherein the user could select 0, 1 or more options.

If you must have checkboxes, and you must use a list in the form definition, then it seems your only option is to create a custom field. You can find documentation on how to do that [here](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/fields.html#custom-fields).

In fact - this use case is the example in the [Custom Widget](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/widgets.html#custom-widgets) portion of the WTForms documentation.

Comment: The case I have is this: an object has multiple files attached to it. I want a render a form which will let users mark the files they want to delete.

Comment: it's been at least two years since I touched WTForms - but if you're using a list in the form definition, as far as I know the only way to do that would be to create a custom widget. It shouldn't be terribly hard to do.

Comment: I haven't really groked the process, but I'll try.